# Page doesnt update despite route url changed

Tags: javascript, url-routing, vite, sveltekit

I am working with sveltekit+vite project. There 3pages here. It should navigate from one page to another page without reloading browser. I am using navigate('/') from 'svelte-routing'.
But the page doesnot update, but route url changes to another one. Here is package json

Part of folder structure:

routes:
result -> +page.svelte
+page.svelte (It should redirect to result page from here.)

```json
{
    "name": "vite-project",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "vite build",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "check": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json",
        "check:watch": "svelte-kit sync && svelte-check --tsconfig ./jsconfig.json --watch",
        "lint": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --check . && eslint .",
        "format": "prettier --plugin-search-dir . --write ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.10",
        "@neoconfetti/svelte": "^1.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0",
        "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",
        "@types/cookie": "^0.5.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "classnames": "^2.3.2",
        "eslint": "^8.28.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^4.0.0",
        "flowbite": "^1.6.3",
        "flowbite-svelte": "^0.29.13",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "postcss-load-config": "^4.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.8.0",
        "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.8.1",
        "svelte": "^3.54.0",
        "svelte-check": "^3.0.1",
        "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.7",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.5",
        "typescript": "^4.9.3",
        "vite": "^4.0.0",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@esbuild/darwin-arm64": "^0.17.5",
        "core-js": "^3.27.2",
        "sass": "^1.58.0",
        "svelte-routing": "^1.6.0"
    }
}
```

It should reload the page to another one.

Comment: You should *not* use a separate router (`svelte-routing`) when you are already using SvelteKit, which has its own routing mechanism.

Comment: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-goto

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `navigate` method from `svelte-routing`

```
<script>
import { navigate } from 'svelte-routing';

const handleClick = () => {
  navigate('/result');
};
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>Go to Result Page</button>
```